# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'articles'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have Django code to backend. But it's not starting because of this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'articles'` StackOverflow people says that you don't have this folder or wrote it wrong in 2 urls.py documents. Here is the structure of my 1st project. Can't you fuys exlain me why this isn;t working?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` file in your `apps` folder?

Comment: i placed  `__init__.py` but problem is still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed the files in the wrong location, your articles folder should be outside the sub myfirst folder and you should not have an app folder.

Comment: what should i do to not delete the app folder and use it like what it has now

Comment: Copy the articles folder outside the myfirst folder then delete the app folder

Comment: i did it but problem is still same

Comment: Have you added it to INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Also can you add a screenshot of your updated structure

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'articles'
]`

Comment: i have added the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221040/discussion-between-ayansh-and-imperions).

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure to have your app in the INSTALLED_APPS list on settings.py once you have moved it to the right location.